# Why I got this error when I open terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

When I open my terminal in macOS, I always get this error. Can anyone help me and give some solution?

```
__conda_activate:13: /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda: bad interpreter: /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens when you type "`which /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`" (without the quotes)?

Comment: I got this "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python not found"

Comment: In what directory did you install Anaconda?